# how to save google dataflow wordcount output into big query table?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am performing dataflow wordcount experiment but after end of that i want to store the output into google big query insted of cloud storage.
experiment -- https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/sample-template
i used following syntex to store the output into cloud storage

python3 -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --region us-central1 --input gs://example/shak/doc.txt --output gs://example/result/output --runner DataflowRunner --project project_name --temp_location gs://example/temp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WriteToBigQuery](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2ad459113134dfffd3caeeb15e821bb644e08663/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1832) PTransform as your sink to write your output data.

A simple example on how to do that - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2ad459113134dfffd3caeeb15e821bb644e08663/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/bigquery_tornadoes.py#L98